# How to get current Controller $scope inside directive function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Sample Link : [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QNAWi4NbRi7nZfSB6GFp?p=preview)

Hi all,

I created one Global Help button in index file based on url am loading dynamic help(html file) which is working fine. I need to identify which controller is activated and i need to pass current $scope as parameter to $scope.HelpFunction function.$scope.HelpFunction available in help directive. In directive I need to get current $scope.message from current controller. based on $scope i need to implement few logic any one help me on this.....

```
  .directive("help", function($location, $window){
    .directive("help", function($location, $window){
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      template: "<button   ng-click=\"HelpFunction( )\">Help</button>",
      scope: true,
      controller: function($scope){
          $scope.HelpFunction = function( ){
            //Here I need to access current  $scope value
            alert($scope.message)
               //var url =$location.url();
               //$window.open(url+ '.html', '', 'width=700,height=700');
          }
      },
      link: function(scope){

      }
    }
  })
.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, router, $location) {
        $scope.message = "Home";
       $scope.TestFunction = function(data) {
        console.log("Home:" + $location.url())
  };

})
.controller('MainController', function ($scope, router) {
        $scope.message = "Main";
       $scope.TestFunction = function(data) {
        console.log("Main:" + data)
  };

})
 .controller('Page1Controller', function ($scope, router) {
    $scope.message = "Page1";
  $scope.TestFunction = function(data) {
       console.log("Page2:" + data)
  };

})
```

Comment: I tried same result. can u share coding?

Comment: What do you mean by "activating" a controller?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you can use the `service`. The `service` will be share data between `controllers`.

Live example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcxeloRCEThUX6VpzTy9?p=preview).

Create `service`.

```
.service('HelpService',function(){
 return {
   message:""
 }
})
```

In `directive`.

```
.directive("help", function($location, $window) {
return {
  restrict: "A",
  template: "<button   ng-click=\"HelpFunction( )\">Help</button>",
  scope: true,
  controller: function($scope,HelpService) {
    console.log($scope)
    $scope.HelpFunction = function() {
      //Here I need to access current  $scope value
      alert(HelpService.message)
        //var url =$location.url();
        //$window.open(url+ '.html', '', 'width=700,height=700');
    }
  },
  link: function(scope) {

  }
}
})
```

In `controller`.

```
 .controller('HomeController', function($scope, router, $location,HelpService) {
HelpService.message = "Home";
console.log(HelpService.message)
$scope.TestFunction = function(data) {
  console.log("Home:" + $location.url())
};
})
```

Comment: This looks more like a work around than the actual solution, sorry

Comment: This is not work around. This solution - **angular** way. `Services` exist for the distribution of data **between** `controllers`. SO is just such a question - how to share the data between different `controllers`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `scope: true` to your returnig array like this

```
module.directive("help", function($location, $window){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: true, // Get the scope of the current Controller
    template: "<button style=\"background-color: #f4f4f4;  color: black;\" ng-click=\"HelpFunction(\'section2\')\"  my-target>Help</button>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.HelpFunction = function(id) {
        var url = $location.url();
        $window.open(url+ '.html', '', 'width=700,height=700');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

UPDATED:

External example http://jsfiddle.net/5gWjY/671/

UPDATED 2 (as requested):

External example http://jsfiddle.net/5gWjY/673/

Comment: inside $scope.HelpFunction  I need to access current $scope

Comment: `$scope.HelpFunction = function(id) { $scope; }`?

Comment: Check the example please

Comment: Can u try with multiple page and controller? @Nevershowmyface

Comment: Ok I'll edit it and post an UPDATED 2. By the way did it work for you?

Comment: Can u send me the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103596/discussion-between-nevershowmyface-and-suresh-b).

Answer (score 0):

Create a factory with a singleton and save the reference of your current scope in it in each controller.

```
factory('currentScope', function(){
   var currentScope = {};

   return currentScope;
})

controller('HomeController', function($scope, currentScope) {
   currentScope = $scope;   
})

controller('MainController', function($scope, currentScope) {
   currentScope = $scope;
})
```

Access the current scope inside your directive.

```
.directive("help", function($location, $window, currentScope){
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      template: "<button   ng-click=\"HelpFunction( )\">Help</button>",
      scope: true,
      controller: function($scope){
          $scope.HelpFunction = function( ){
            //Here I need to access current  $scope value
            console.log(currentScope);

            alert($scope.message)
               //var url =$location.url();
               //$window.open(url+ '.html', '', 'width=700,height=700');
          }
      },
      link: function(scope){

      }
    }
  })
```

You will have to assign a controller to your view.

```
$stateProvider.state('Home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'Home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            });
```

Comment: Always return {} object only @Charlie H

Comment: Please implement this solution correctly. It will not return {} then.

Comment: I implemented same what ur mentioned @charlie H

Comment: can u give me runable link?

Comment: Assign a controller to your template via `$stateProvider`. This way your controller is executed and the `currentScope` factory is updated. Answer updated.